# Azure B2C SSO login with 2 apps

Tags: php, symfony, azure-ad-b2c

following problem:
I have 2 apps. Each app is registered in azure b2c and therefore has its own sign-in policy.
The login in each app works separately and without problems.
Now I want to log in from App 1 to App 2. When I call App 2 from App1 and send the token from App 1, I get an error.
It works if I use only one policy for both apps, but that's not right. You need a separate policy for each app.
How do I log from App1 to App2?
developed in php and symphon

Comment: You shouldn't exchange tokens between apps. Each app should redirect to Azure AD B2C where the SSO session is managed. For each policy, what have you set the "Single sign-on configuration" setting to? If you set this to "Tenant", then all B2C apps and policies share the same session.

Comment: yes is on tenant

Comment: If it is set to "Tenant", then you will be redirected from the second app to Azure AD B2C but, in the same browser, you shouldn't be prompted to sign in to this second app. You aren't adding the "prompt=login" parameter to the authentication request are you?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answer.

I have the parameters in the url
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_reg_sign_app1&client_id=xxxxxx&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https://xxx/resulttoken&scope=openid&response_type=code+id_token&prompt=login&response_mode=form_post
but I'm not logged.

app1 calls the url and I log in.
If I call now in the same browser app 2 url is called
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_reg_sign_app2&client_id=yyyyy&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https://yyy/resulttoken&scope=openid&response_type=code+id_token&prompt=login&response_mode=form_post

Every time I have to log in again